# Managing user accounts for different sites with one database

Tags: database, user-accounts

We now have one site running but we will need to build a branded site for our client soon. The client site will have exactly the same data set as our current site expect for the user data. The client site must have totally separated user info which allows only the client to use the site.

I don't see the need for setting up a new database or creating a new user table for the client. My tentative solution is add a "Company" column for the user table so that I can differ which site the user data row is on.

I do not know if this approach will work or not or if it is the best practice. Could anyone with experience like this shed some light on this question?

Thanks,
Nigong

P.S. I use LAMP with AWS.

Comment: what database are you using? what technology stack? etc. Approaches will vary based on that and many other things.

Comment: if the data structures will never need to be changed to accomodate something only ONE of the clients needs, then go with a single table and an extra "companyID" field. but once you start getting into custom stuff, then go with separate tables. think of how painful it'd be having to special-case all kinds of junk in the logic to do `if (client_id == you) { fieldX is for purposeY} else { fieldx is for purposeZ}`

Comment: @m4tt1mus I am using LAMP with AWS.

Comment: @MarcB You hit my pain point man. We don't see any customization needed for the client now. But who knows the future... But anyway, thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Using an extra column to store a company / entity id is a common approach for multitenant system. In general you will want to abstract the part that that verifies you can only retrieve data you're allowed to a piece that all queries go through, like your ORM. This will prevent people new to the project from exposing/using data that shouldn't be exposed/used.